# Disable `indent-relative`

Tags: indentation

What's the right way to disable Emacs' default `indent-relative` behaviour and make sure that `TAB` always indents by a single level (be it a tab or whitespace character)?

There doesn't seem to much information about this in Emacs, but I get the impression that perhaps `tab-stop-list` is part of the solution if I remap `indent-relative` to `tab-to-tab-stop`.

Comment: `indent-relative` is a function that is defined to add sufficient whitespace to align the current line relative to the previous line. If what you really want is `tab-to-tab-stop`, you should use that instead, rather than redefining `indent-relative`. In many modes, `M-i` is bound to `tab-to-tab-stop`, and you can always bind it to something more convenient (including possibly whatever `indent-relative` is bound to in the mode).

Comment: You're right, I realised my mistake with `tab-to-tab-stop` later. Thanks for clarifying. For the time being I only bound TAB to `indent-for-tab-command`. Fancy adding an answer or shall I answer my own question based on your inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `tab-to-tab-stop`, just do so! `tab-to-tab-stop` and `indent-relative` are different functions, designed to do different things. Different modes will bind one or the other (or something else) to TAB, according to what the mode writer thought would be most convenient. If you prefer to use something other than the default, just rebind the key to use your preferred function.

Redefining the function, particularly with built-in functions, is likely to cause unexpected problems later on.