# `tab-stop-list` being ignored

Tags: indentation, major-mode

Tying to write a new mode, I am stuck at:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode NEWS-mode
  text-mode "NEWS"
  "Major mode for NEWS file."
  (setq tab-stop-list '(2 6 59 65))
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (setq indent-relative 'tab-to-tab-stop)
  )
```

Pressing TAB in the 1st line of the file has the desired result of jumping to column 2, 6, 59 then 65.

But when pressing TAB in a line with text above it, then it jumps to the word-start positions of the previous line and ignores `tab-stop-list`.

I found [Disable `indent-relative`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/44113/28353) and it says one should not re-define `indent-relative` (which does not do what I want anyway).

So how to ditch that `indent-relative` behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information about Emacs indentation commands [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html).
To get the desired indent behavior you want to use  the function bound to `M-i` (`tab-to-tab-stop`).

The docstring of `indent-for-tab-command` (TAB), mentions that for indentation it calls the function set by the `indent-line-function`. By default, this variable is set to `indent-relative`. Simply set it to `tab-to-tab-stop` to achieve the desired behavior.

```lisp
(setq indent-line-function 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

I guess you could locally set this (use `setq-local`) within your major-mode definition.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does the trick.